# getting an error trying to sign-up on heroku

Tags: heroku

this is the screenshot of the error i am getting after signing-up.
[i have tried every possible way to try to connect with heroku support but i'm unable to contact them as they want me to login to contact them. but without an account how can i even contact them.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6LGPN.png)

i have tried to signup but not able to do so.
here are the things i have alreay tried:

- use another browser
- use my smartphone
- tried typing manually.
  but still getting this error.

i don't know what to do now, can someone please help me out.